# onclick javascript function won't work in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've never really heard of something this simple working in every browser, but firefox, so can anyone shed some light on this?

```
 <a href="javascript:" onclick="quoteMe('name','id','yourname');" id="quote" style="border:1px solid white;color:#F1F1F1; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;reply&nbsp;</a>
```

and

jQuery:

```
    var nameForm;
function quoteMe(commenterName, id, name) {
if (name == "")
nameForm = 'Name: <input type="text" class="input" name="username" value="" />'
else
nameForm = '<div class="outlineTitle2">'+name+'</div>'+'<input type="hidden" class="input" name="username" value="'+name+'" />'
 if (jQuery("#replyForm"+id).length == 0) {
jQuery("#"+id).append('<form method="post" id="replyForm'+id+'"><br /><input type="hidden" name="cid" value="'+id+'" /><input type="hidden" name="nameOfTable" value="articles" />'+nameForm+'<br />Reply: <input type="text" class="input" name="commentReply" value="'+commenterName+'" style="width:80%" /><input type="submit" value="POST" name="addReply" class="bigButton" /></form>');
}
else {
jQuery("#replyForm"+id).remove();
}
```

}

More updates below under first answer.
http://cl.ly/082z3g04381G3r1i2e08

Comment: @Swith as some of the best practices..if you are not using href attribute , better use div approach. a hrefs are used for SEO purposes. The easiest way to find error in your code is , install firebug and put a break point in quoteMe and check if its workig or not.If not start with printing alert. You can easily find the problem...do you have firebug installed.

Comment: @switz , i think something is breaking in your code and your javascript is not getting executed.

Comment: There are no errors. When I click it, nothing happens and no errors appear. I'll try the div approach and get back to you.  I have firebug installed. Thanks

Comment: The thing is, that it works flawlessly without errors in Chrome, Safari, etc.  It gives no errors in firefox, just never really executes. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: no problem switz , you can easily fix it , probably your cache might not have cleared or something elase , normally firefox is mostly developer friendly...we can easily fix your problem. I will be online for another 1 hour..lets fix your isssue.

Comment: Although semicolons are not required at the end of a statement, it is a best practice to include semicolons.  A similar rule for braces exist; you should include start and end braces even if they are not required for easier readability and debugging.  See 'semicolons' and 'required blocks' http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Comment: `border=1px solid white;color:#F1F1F1; font-weight:bold;`  should be  `border: 1px solid white;color:#F1F1F1; font-weight:bold;`

Comment: @switz , don't forget to enable errors on console...then only it shows errors.

Comment: does your script tag have a type in it? <script type="text/javoscrapt"> I seem to recall an onclick not working for me once because I had done type="test/javascript" - you could also try doing <a href="javascript:quoteMe(...)" > and see if that works

Comment: @Zevan you are right , thats why we should avoid onclick events for a href ...// yeah even i remember giving as javascript: for hrefs and img clicks

Comment: @switz , whats the final issue, little excited to see your error...

Comment: I've tried all these, you can see what I wrote below. It just is stubborn!

Comment: Oh thanks for everything! I've +1'd everything that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a `form` as a child of a `table` element. Either use the table's parent node, or add a cell.

(For reference, a properly indented version of the source:

```
var nameForm;

function quoteMe(commenterName, id, name) {
    if (name == "") {
        nameForm = 'Name: <input type="text" class="input" name="username" value="" />'
    }
    else {
        nameForm = '<div class="outlineTitle2">' + name + '</div>' +
                   '<input type="hidden" class="input" name="username" value="' + name + '" />'
    }
    if (jQuery("#replyForm" + id).length == 0) {
        jQuery("#" + id).append('<form method="post" id="replyForm' + id + '">' +
                                  '<br />' +
                                  '<input type="hidden" name="cid" ' +
                                  '       value="' + id + '" />' +
                                  '<input type="hidden" name="nameOfTable" ' +
                                  '       value="articles" />' +
                                  nameForm + '<br />' +
                                  'Reply: <input type="text" class="input" ' +
                                  '              name="commentReply" ' +
                                  '              value="' + commenterName + '"' +
                                  '              style="width:80%" />' +
                                  '<input type="submit" value="POST" ' +
                                  '       name="addReply" class="bigButton" />' +
                                '</form>');
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#replyForm" + id).remove();
    }
}
```

).

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace `quoteMe` by `alert` and see what happens.
If an alert pops up, it means you have a problem in your function.

The inline events work fine on Firefox too, here is common call I use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fn(this, param1, param2)">label</a>
```

even shorter:

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="fn(this, param1, param2)">label</a>
```

- if you use href="#", you need to `return false` at the `onclick` call, otherwise, the hash key will change in the address bar. It can be annoying, especially in ajax based apps.
- it is often useful to pass to the function `this`, it will give you the reference to the clicked `<a>`. You don't have to play with id's to find it back.

Comment: very nice explanation...let me give you +1 :)

Comment: Okay, so after some investigation.  The function runs and the code is placed in the correct spot. In firebug its greyed out though and doesn't appear. Any idea why it might just be greyed out?

Comment: Okay so, it's setting display:none; according to firebug computed style. Even if I manually change the display or the css to block or inline, it stays none.  I've never seen anything like this. The ids don't overlap.  It works fine in every other browser. Ahh!!!!